# Magento2: AddToCartUrl for Guest user

Tags: magento2, addtocart, guest-checkout

I have generated an **addtoCartUrl** using

**\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct**

```
$aux = $this->_listProduct->getAddToCartUrl($product) ."?form_key=". $this->_formKey->getFormKey() . "&qty=1";
```

It works for logged users but NOT for Guest users

Any idea?

Comment: Guest users are seeing probably block loaded from cache. Check if disabling full page and block html resolves the problem. If so you will need to write a js function that will hook into clicking on that link and add form_key to the request. The formkey itself need to be fetched from some endpoint (not sure if there is such already or would you have to create one).